# I need to select a div tag that has a specific child tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div class = "some class">
    <h4>X1</h4>
    <a href="www.someurl.com">Value of X1</a>
</div>
```

I need to select the div that has the certain h4 matching text X1. By using find_all() with specific attributes and then again using find_all to go to the h4 selects the h4 not the div itself. I need to select the div.

And if the above is possible, any way to access the 'a' tag directly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `findNext` method.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<div class = "some class">
    <h4>X1</h4>
    <a href="www.someurl.com">Value of X1</a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all("h4", text="X1"):     #Find all h4 with required text. 
    print(tag.findNext("a").text)
```

**Output:**

```
Value of X1
```